# How to add a WHERE filter for dates using OLE for Excel?

Tags: vba, date, excel, oledb

I'm trying to create a SQL query that has a WHERE clause that uses dates. I'm querying an Excel sheet using OLE.
Using functions such as CAST or CONVERT won't work

Comment: Can you update your question with the query you have tried out?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to enclose the date in #. To avoid regional issues, the best way is to pass an ISO format for the date. Just consider that some "databases wanna be" (I'm not able to call Access a db) just accept US date literals in the queries.
For example (using ISO date format)

```
Function WriteQuery(d as Date) as String

  WriteQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sometable WHERE DateColumnName < " & "#" & Format(d,"YYYY-MM-DD") & "#"

End Function
```

Comment: So did you get it solved? `cast` `convert` works with SQL Server, but not with MS ACCESS or EXCEL OLE ;)